# How can I disable Cipher Suites for Apache2

Tags: apache2, lets-encrypt, certbot

I've done a bit of research into this and I'm stumped, I was wondering if someone could give me some pointers.

I have an SSL certificate for my root domain and different SSL certificates for a few other sub domains.
I've opened port 80 only for certbot automatic renewal, all http requests are automatically redirected to https, i've tested this using the dry run flag with no issues.

I've now got the point where I'm testing the security of my server and certificates.
I've only allowed TLS 1.3 and lower versions of tls and therefore their ciphers should be disabled.

My ssl.conf file in mods-enabled has this specified:
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

However no matter what I do this SSL testing site still reports I'm using weak ciphers.
Website I'm using to test my site: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Ciphers it reports I'm still using which are weak:

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)

TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x67)

TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33)

TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x6b)

TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)

TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9c)

TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9d)

TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x3c)

TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x3d)

TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)

Comment: 1/2) Some advice. 1) Unless you really know what you are doing, don't. Encryption is for the experienced. 2) Weak ciphers may or may not be a problem. Do you understand the impact of disabling or enabling a cipher? 3) Getting an A on ssllabs.com might be good or it might block half your customers. Which clients/browsers and which versions of those browsers do you need to support? 4) There are many articles on the Internet on how to get an A. I recommend reading a few so that you have a better understanding. 5) In my opinion, supporting TLSv1.2 and better is good enough today.

Comment: 2/2) The **openssl** tool can help you understand which ciphers are being used. Example: **openssl ciphers MEDIUM  | tr ":" "\n"**. You can pass the entire **SSLCipherSuite** string: **openssl ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM  | tr ":" "\n"** This will help you fine tune which ciphers will be enabled.

Comment: 3) Experiment with this **strong** cipher suite: **SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL** for your tests.

Comment: Thankyou but based on SSL labs results id be excluding windows 7 users and some old browsers I'd prefer higher security over usability for the time being. Turns out lets encrypt had an include that was superseding my config, I corrected that conf file as a work around for the time being but I may revert the changes once I'm up and running.

Comment: Good. Now is you have a future client compatibility problem, you will know where to look to solve it. There are a lot more clients than just web browsers. Applications that use their own libraries often are not updated for many years. Old browsers are generally not a problem for the server, it is a problem for the client machine's security. Post an answer that explains your solution so that others benefit.

Comment: I used the Mozilla SSL generator here:
https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=apache&version=2.4.41&config=modern&openssl=1.1.1k&guideline=5.6

I need to alter the cipher suite anyway in the future because apparently lets encrypt maintains this as it upgrades

Answer (score 2):

In the Apache conf file, I use :-

```
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!MEDIUM:!SSLv3:!kRSA:!SHA1:!SHA256:!SHA384:!DSS:!aNULL;
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
```

and this seems to avoid the necessity of specifying each cipher allowed, yet still gives the highest ciphers only.